# Executing Oracle function in where statement

Tags: oracle, plsql

How I can use Oracle function (created) in where statement? I have something like this:

```
SELECT a, b, c
FROM x.y
WHERE d = function('x')
```

Comment: I created it, but I don't know have I can use it in this case.

Comment: What you posted is exactly the correct way to call it. Did you try it? What happened? Did you get an error? What was it? Did you get an unexpected result? Then maybe the function doesn't do what you think it does.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try below it will work for you

```
SELECT a, b, c
FROM x,y
WHERE d = (select function('x') from dual);
```

Using PLSQL Anonymous block.

```
declare

z number;

begin

SELECT a
into z
FROM test
WHERE a = late_return_fee (2,3);

end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Given a function defined in the SQL scope:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnct( value VARCHAR2 ) RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
BEGIN
  RETURN value;
END;
/
```

You can call it exactly as you stated in the question:

```
SELECT *
FROM   DUAL
WHERE  dummy = fnct( 'X' );
```

Or in PL/SQL:

```
DECLARE
  value VARCHAR2(10);
BEGIN
  SELECT dummy
  INTO   value
  FROM   DUAL
  WHERE  dummy = fnct('X');
END;
/
```